# Effective way to use CSV of DNA information as database in Django project

Tags: django, django-models

I am thinking about the design of the following Django project.
In this project, I have a CSV file (4 columns, 500 rows) which I am not sure how to handle as the database.
[the CSV looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43EBw.png)
The data contains 500 codes where each code has 3 scores: f1, f2, f3.
**The website goal**: 1. to get the input of the user of what feature columns data he is interested in and in which order.
e.g: 2X**f2** 1X**f1** (there are only 3 feature columns: f1, f2, f3 and 'code' column) 
2. to generate an output of codes that contains the highest-ranking codes for the required features in the required order.

so for our input: 2X**f2** 1X**f1**
the output will be the following string: `[#1 rankning code f2 column] [#2 ranking code f2 column] [#1 rankning code f1 column]`

I was thinking about creating a database with 3 columns: f1, f2, f3 where in each column there are codes in descending order, so if the user wants 5 codes from f1 I will take the first 5.

My question is:
How to handle the database in a simple way for developing and maintaining it (not looking for efficiency) that will use Django tools properly?

My first direction was using MySql and django models to map the data.
I would appreciate any thoughts or tips for learning Django as I am using the official documentation that provides example of "pool" website which is not what I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd design the models as I understand your problem.

```
class Field(models.Model):
    # This model represents each of the individual fX fields, so f1, f2, f3
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)


class Code(models.Model):
    # This model represents the values in the first column, code.
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class FieldData(models.Model):
    code = models.ForeignKey(Code, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field = models.ForeignKey(Field, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('code', 'field')]
```

Then when you process a CSV, you'd:

- Read the header row and use `Field.objects.get_or_create` for each of the columns following Code.
- Read the body to create `Code` instance and `FieldData` instances for each Field column in the row.

The model design would have to change if you need history for the FieldData instances.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer!
Using this model might be a great way to map my csv data!
I have 3 questions:
1) What is an easy way to actually parse the CSV to go row by row and add those objects?

2) Why wouldn't the following model be simpler (while knowning that there will not be any change in the fields):

```
class Code(models.model):
code = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
f1_score = models.IntegerField()
f2_score = models.IntegerField()
f3_score = models.IntegerField()
```

3) How would you extract each time the highest-ranking codes from each field? e.g 5 best ranking on f1